# Ajax requests pending

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Since 2 days my ajax request stop completing and are stuck on pending (a few do complete sometimes and then the rest is stuck), for example the following script;

```
  <script>
      setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'update-test.php'
        });
      },1000);
      </script>
```

Updatetest.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
  echo 'logged in';
  #do stuff
} else {
  echo 'not logged in ';
}
?>
```

I haven't changed anything at all, it all was working perfectly before. I've been trying our different things and figured out that it has to do something with sessions. When not using sessions in the script it works fine. I've also added session_write_close(); so I only read and not block other requests but this did not seem to help. My hosting provider said nothing was wrong on their end, which I'm not to sure about..

Does anyone know whats causing it? Help is appreciated.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  Take a look at the `xhrFields` example.  If you want to use sessions with ajax, you most likely want to make sure the ajax sends all available cookies for the domain on the request.  Edit: looks like it is a same origin request so may not be the issue, but doesn't hurt

Comment: @Taplar Tried it but no difference unfortunately.